# Create a 2-d Array using Numpy.eye with custom values for 0's and a custom diagonal

Tags: python, numpy

in short I'm trying to create a 2-d array using np.eye where the 0's and the diagonal have custom values.

I figured for the diagonal, if I do

a=np.eye(4)
b=1.8*a

the diagonal changes to 1.8 but changing the 0's are still a mystery to me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `b=1.8*a+8.1` ?

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because you want some other value instead of *0* (outside the diagonal)
you can't base your function on *eye*, but rather on *full* and then
set diagonal elements to your custom value, using *diag_indices*.

So define your function as:

```
def customEye(N : int, diagVal : float, otherVal : float):
    a = np.full((N, N), otherVal)
    a[np.diag_indices(N)] = diagVal
    return a
```

Then, when you call `arr = customEye(4, 1.8, 0.5)` the result is:

```
array([[1.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
       [0.5, 1.8, 0.5, 0.5],
       [0.5, 0.5, 1.8, 0.5],
       [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.8]])
```